# Simple Load data button with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am a newbie with firebase and am trying to translate a simple "loadData" Button with Angularjs with a Firebase source instead of $http.get call in order to test my data source.

Basically I am trying to create something like this:[onclick Load data](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2013/12/12/angularjspart-4-accessing-server-side-resources/) to pull data from JSON Firebase DM. However I am running into lost in translation issues, especially as I am doing this in a bigger project which already loads controllers in one big file:

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
  function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https:<DATASOURCE>.firebaseio.com/");

  //Nothing Happens
  $scope.loadPosts = function(){
  $scope.Posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
}
  //This Prints in The Console
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  },
    function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}]);
```

The scope does not give me much clue except for the following:
    `TypeError: $firebaseArray(...).success is not a function`
And I do have my dependencies in the page including angular ire and firebase as well as par of my angular app (all in separate files). The Posts.html view contains the following:

```
 //EDITED: Added an ng-repeat for posts
 <button ng-click="loadPosts()">Load Posts</button>
 <div ng-repeat="post in Posts">
    <h3>{{post.Title}}</h3>
    <p>{{post.Body}}</p>
 </div>
```

The State provider builds my controller and pushes it inside ng-view in the index page:

```
 .state('Blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as posts',
    templateUrl: 'Posts.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })
```

My guess is that I am making some wrong reference calls with my function above but do not know how to replace them with the firebase equivalent. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire has [detailed documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html), which you should read through. As the error states, `$firebaseArray` has no `success()` method. The simplest solution is this:

```
$scope.loadPosts = function() {
  $scope.Posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
};
```

If you want add error handling, then use `$loaded()`.

```
$scope.loadPosts = function() {
  $firebaseArray(ref).$loaded().then(function(posts) {
    $scope.Posts = posts;
  }, function(error) {
    alert("The Data is not loading");
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey, this is not working for me. I tried adding an ng-repeat="post in Posts" in my Posts.html file to collect the data after I click the button but nothing. Weirdly I am getting these errors in firebug which I do not know if they are related: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'arraybuffer').